# HTML parsed through $compile, ng-model not binding in isolation for ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angular-directive

I am building an Angular module that will allow a form to be built dynamically.

As elements are selected, HTML is added to a model. The model is attached to an `ng-repeat` element.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list1 track by $index">
  <div compiledom="item.content"></div>
</div>
```

So an `item` in the model might look like this:

```
{
 'title': 'Full-Column Text',
 'drag': true,
 'inputValue': '',
 'content': '<div class="small-12 columns"><input type="text" dynamic-model="$index" placeholder="Full Width Text" /></div>'
}
```

I am using a custom directive to compile the HTML fed to the model.

```
.directive('compiledom', function($compile) {
 return function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.$watch(
    function(scope) {
      return scope.$eval(attrs.compiledom);
    },
    function(value) {
      element.html(value);
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
  );
 }
})
```

And using a second directive to bind the model data to the input field in that HTML.

```
.directive('dynamicModel', function($compile) {
 return function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.$watch(attrs.dynamicModel, function(dynamicModel) {
    if (attrs.ngModel || attrs.ngModel == dynamicModel || !dynamicModel) return;

    element.attr('ng-model', 'item.inputValue'); <---------- bound here

    if (dynamicModel == '') element.removeAttr('ng-model');
    element.unbind();
    $compile(element)(scope);
  });
 }
})
```

My issue is that whatever I put into an input field gets placed to every input element. For some reason, it appears that a single `item.inputValue` is getting reflected to every `item` of the same type. The model is bound, but I have broken something in ng-repeat that keeps it in isolation.

For example, if I have two 'Full-Column Text' inputs, if one is set to 'ABC', both are set to 'ABC'. If I also were to have 2 'Half-Column Text' inputs, they would remain unset until I set one of them to 'DCE' - then they are both set to 'DCE'.

A link to a demo/example of the issue will be shared soon.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, my directives were fine.

When I was adding to my model, I was using `.slice`. This was causing a reflection issue. Using `angular.copy` made a geniune clone, allowing the isolation I was looking for.

`$scope.list1[x] =  angular.copy($scope.list5[x]);`